# Get JIRA issue using JIRA 5.0.1 REST JSON API using a .NET client

Tags: json, jira, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I'm new to working with REST based services, but I want to do is something which I had hoped would be quite easy, that is, get a JIRA issue and display it using a .NET Framework 4.5 client.

I've found that I can get a JSON response by pasting the following URI into a browser:
https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/issue/JRA-9

What I need to do though is call this from a .net app.  So after some research I've figured that using the HTTPClient in .NET 4.5 is the way to go.

In order to run the following test code you will need to be referencing .NET Framework 4.5 and have added references to System.Net.Http and extensions System.Net.Http and System.Json:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Json;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JIRAClient3
{
    class Program
    {
        static string _address = "https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/issue/JRA-9";

        static async void Run()
        {
            // Create an HttpClient instance
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = int.MaxValue;

            // Send a request asynchronously continue when complete
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(_address);

            // Check that response was successful or throw exception
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            // Read response asynchronously as JsonValue
            JsonArray content = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JsonArray>();

            // Exception occurs at the above line, which is:
            //System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
            //HResult=-2146233079
            //Message=The input stream contains too many delimiter characters which may 
            //be a sign that the incoming data may be malicious.
            //Source=System.Net.Http.Formatting

            // I then need to write out the contents of the JSON/JIRA issue.
      }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             Run();
             Console.WriteLine("Hit ENTER to exit...");
             Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm stuck at the exception to do with too many delimiters.  My questions therefore are:

- Am I heading in the right sort of direction with this?
- How can I resolve the too many delimiters exception.
- Once the exception is resolved, what is the best way to then access parts of the JSON response such as the JIRA issue tile and description etc?

Many thanks

Paul

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this error by following the instructions posted here: http://forums.asp.net/post/4845421.aspx.

However, it is advisable to use a Json.NET based formatter which will ship out of the box upon the next drop of ASP.NET Web API.  If you're not willing to wait and comfortable compiling the code yourself, you can get it now by pulling latest from Microsoft's open source repository: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/.  The formatter you want can specifically be found here: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/5ac8586b78b3#src%2fSystem.Net.Http.Formatting%2fFormatting%2fJsonMediaTypeFormatter.cs.